# Print all document from folder in Google Drive with Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, printing, google-cloud-print

I want to print all documents with Google Apps Script. I added my printer in Google Cloud but I can't find any procedure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Google Apps Printing**

Printing can be a tough issue and it also depends upon the device your using.  There is no print command in Google Apps Script.  In dialogs or webapps you can try to using window.print and that might work depending upon your browser.  Fortunately, most mobile apps have a variety of ways to print the current page but they tend to be different for each device.  I know you would like to have a consistent solution that always works I would too.  But I've learned to live with out it.